# How do you return to the prompt with access to all objects after a script is finished?

Tags: python, scripting, terminal

I am working on a script which generates a lot of objects and variables when run, and I need a way to interact with these in the console before the process terminates. Using the `input()` trick is not enough as it will just wait for keypress but not send it to the prompt.
When running my script in eclipse I have found no way to make it stay open after run.

```
def foo():
   print('Hi')

def bar():
   print('How are you?')


def main():
   foo()
   bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-i` option:

```
python -i /path/to/script.py
```

According to [Command line and environment - Miscellaneous options](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options):

> `-i`
>
> When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command, even
>   when sys.stdin does not appear to be a terminal. The PYTHONSTARTUP
>   file is not read.
>
> This can be useful to inspect global variables or a stack trace when a
>   script raises an exception. See also PYTHONINSPECT.

---

Another way: As the documentation said, you can also set the environment variable `PYTHONINSPECT`

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import os
   os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = '1'
   main()
```

BTW, the code in the question misspelled `__main__` (not `main`).